# How can I know tesseract has been set up successfully

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tesseract

I set up my tesseract 3.01 in visual studio 2008 according to http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMePre3

No errors report in compilication.

Then a console command window saying clustering flash by, then disappear.

If I have successfully installed it, where should I put tesseract examples? Is it Ok to put them under the vs2008 folder?

Can anyone send me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking out the complete source from [Tesseract SVN repositoty](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/checkout), open tesseract solution from vs2008 folder, select LIB-Release configuration, and build. The .exe output files can be found in vs2008\LIB_Release folder. You can move them to the parent folder of vs2008, where there are some sample images and tessdata, open a command prompt, and run your test from there.

```
tesseract phototest.tif out
```

Comment: I don't have LIB-Release. I only have debug, release.dynamic, and release.static.

Comment: Sounds like you have an older version. You can select either release configuration and build; I don't remember exactly where it would place the output .exe. The setup I described was for 3.02, which is what currently in the repository.